# HTML JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have decided to go another way because this is an assignment for Computer Science 101 class and i need to present simple html code with java script usage. Anyway, i have another code. the problem with this code is when a person chooses A in the second question I want the code to check if a person chose A or B in the first question. Take a look at the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <h1>Quiz</h1><br>
    <hr>

    <form>
        <ol>
            <li>Do you know when is Canada Day?

                <p><input onclick="myFunction2()" type=
                'button' value='A'> Yes</p>

                <p><input type=
                'button' value='B'> No</p>

                <p></p>
                <hr>

                <p></p>
            </li>

            <li>Do you celebrate Canada Day?

                <p><input onclick="myFunction3()" type=
                'button' value='A'> Yes</p>

                <p><input onclick="myFunction1()" type=
                'button' value='B'> No</p>

                <p></p>
                <hr>

                <p></p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </form>
    <script>
    var x;
    function myFunction1()
    {
        alert('You have to learn more about Canada Day!')
    }

    function myFunction2()
    {
        x=1;
    }

    function myFunction3()
    {
    if (x=1)
    {
        alert('You are a true Canadian')
    }
    else
    {
        alert('You have to learn more')
    }
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not writing inline Javascript first of all.

You want to set up event handlers for you buttons, this would require you to assign a class name to them in order to set up our event listener. For the sake of simplicity I am going to use jQuery to do this.

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4g8mywb/6/) i created for you.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <center><h1>Quiz</h1></center><hr>
        <p>Do you know when is Canada Day?<p>
        <button class="canadaButtonYes">Yes<p>
        <button class="canadaButtonNo">No<p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.canadaButtonYes').on('click', function() {
        answer = confirm('Do you celebrate Canada day?');
        if (answer === true)
            alert('You are a true canadian!');
        else 
            alert('You should learn more!');
    });

    $('.canadaButtonNo').on('click', function() {
        alert("You should learn more!");
    });

});
```

Best of luck to you.